# Basic require.js example

Tags: javascript, html, requirejs

index.html

```
<html>

    <head>
        <script data-main="main" src="http://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.1.8/minified/require.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body></body>

</html>
```

main.js

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        jquery: 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min'
    }
});

define(['jquery'], function ($) {
    console.log($);
});
```

Why does `console.log` give me undefined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[AMD support](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/b693b370a459ef89ef187518b832a45b6e848eca/src/exports/amd.js#L12) (which is required by RequireJS) [has been added to jQuery 1.7](http://blog.jquery.com/2011/11/03/jquery-1-7-released/), and you are trying to use jQuery 1.6.

In order to use jQuery 1.6 with RequireJS, try adding shim configuration:

```
requirejs.config({
  paths: {
    jquery: 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min'
  },
  shim: {
    jquery: {exports: '$'}
  }
});
```

Alternatively, you can use newer version of jQuery (at least 1.7):

```
requirejs.config({
  paths: {
    jquery: 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min'
  }
});
```